# hide elements during print and show after print is complete

Tags: jquery, html, printing

http://www.highcharts.com/demo
this link contains jquery chart. There is a **print** option at the top right corner of the chart demo. It hides elements during print which is easy to do but it shows all the elements after print. It means they detect if print is completed or not. How to implement this print-technology in my own webpage?

Answer (score 0):

There are javascript events for this. As you can see in this code, taken from: 
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

```
(function() {
    var beforePrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run before printing.');
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        console.log('Functionality to run after printing');
    };

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

window.onbeforeprint and window.onafterprint are supported in IE5+ and Firefox6+, but for Webkit browsers there is a workaround with window.matchMedia.

This solution doesn't work for Opera though, just Firefox, IE and WebKit browsers.